# Integrate Cocos2d with Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, augmented-reality, cocos3d

I would like to integrate Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK with Cocos2d or 3d to create an app.  I would like to do something similar to the multi markers example they have provided where I want it to recognize an object and have 2d images appear on the screen that is all apart of a game.  I'm just not sure how to integrate the two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the source Code Link

http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1220/

Hope this will help you.